# matrix inverse and limit

Tags: matrices, limits, inverse

I would like to get a better understanding of limits and matrix inverses, specifically the relationship between:

$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}(\mathbf{A}^{-1})$ and $(\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{A})^{-1}$  (*)

where $\mathbf{A} = \left[\begin{array}{c c}
{\mathbf{B}} & \mathbf{b}\\
\mathbf{b}^{'} & k
\end{array}\right]$
and $k$ is a scalar. Lets assume that $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible for all $k$.

Clearly the terms in (*) are not equivalent.  However, lets say that I want to take the ratio of two elements of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$.  Say I want to evaluate:

$r = \frac{\mathbf{A}^{-1}_{i,n}}{\mathbf{A}^{-1}_{j,n}}$.

I can apply the matrix inversion lemma and get an expression of the following form:

$r = \frac{\frac{1}{k+c}{h}}{\frac{1}{k+c}{g}}$ (this form will only works for certain elements)

where $c,h,g$ are some scalars that can be calculated using the matrix inversion lemma and more importantly, $h,g$ do not depend on $k$.  We see that the terms that **do** depend on $k$ cancel and we are left with $r = \frac{h}{g}$.  From this I conclude that the ratio of certain elements of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ do not depend on $k$.

I'm a little unsure how to justify this rigorously. My final result for $r$ is correct but it seems that I'm taking the ratio of two elements of the inverse without regard for what $k$ is and then canceling terms. If on the other hand I assume that $k \rightarrow \infty$ before taking the inverse, I would get something very different.

Comment: How do you invert a matrix with an undefined entry, as in the second form?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  It's not undefined.  Assume that $A$ is an $n$ x $n$ matrix. $B$ is an $(n-1)$ x $(n-1)$ matrix. $b$ is a $(n-1)$ x $1$ vector and $k$ is some scalar. Using the matrix inversion lemma I can write each element of $A^{-1}$ explicitly in terms of elements of $B^{-1}$ , $b$ and $k$.  Thus, I can see how the value of $k$ impacts various terms in the inverse.  Hopefully this is more clear

Comment: This reasoning applies to the first limit. In the second you take first the limit of the matrix components, i.e., set $k=\infty$, which gives a non-matrix.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement for the exact form of the inverse of a block matrix.